# press number keypad to achieve game result input

Tags: java, swing

press “1”+“Enter”on keyboard,it will show the red circle,then press"2"+"Enter"on keyboard it will show blue circle in another column and vice versa.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et0K6.png]

What components should be used ? jtable? or anything else.  Any idea to achieve it.  (by the way , i am trying to do is the baccarat roadmap)

Comment: Display image in the question

Comment: Create a panel that uses a GridLayout. Create and add an empty JLabel to each grid. Then when the KeyStroke is invoked you can add either a blue or red Icon to the appropriate JLabel.

Comment: @camickr,  sorry for reply ur answer late. u really point out the path to solve my problem. I still work on my project once i have time.